# Is this Chrome SSL warning expected behavior?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Chrome threw an [SSL warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KW6K.png) at me when I tried to login. This is the story of how it all went down.

## Earlier today

I created an account on the Network Engineering Stack Exchange site. I created the account by logging in using a Google Account, and then I posted a question. I did this on an iOS device using Chrome.

## Just now

I was browsing SO and saw a notification for +100 rep on Network Engineering, and clicked on it. It brought me to the page explaining reputation. I noticed I was not logged in, despite being logged into Stack Overflow with the same Google Account. I clicked the login link located in the black horizontal bar at the top of the page and was presented with the warning.

[image: I encountered this Chrome moderate SSL warning on Network Engineering Stack Exchange]

I understand why Chrome threw this warning at me, but I wasn't sure if this was the behavior intended by the Stack Exchange developers, or if they didn't know about it. Personally, I think this warning may scare less experienced users away, so I felt obligated to post about just in case no one knew about it yet.

Comment: SSL does not work yet on the per-site metas, that part is expected. But the links should not use HTTPS in this case, that part is a bug.

Comment: Doesn't this question is not about meta site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll route logins through HTTP on child metas again as of revision `2014.3.12.1449`.

Thanks for the report!